# TextInput clear text on icon press not clearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to set the value of my custom TextInput to "" when the `iconPress` is called.
The problem is, that when i call the `iconPress`, it should clear the text of my `TextInputCode` field.
But it isnt updated on my screen, isnt clearing the input field.
But it just doesnt change the value/clear it...

This is my code:

```
     const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState("");
     const submitHandler = () => { 
        setSearchString("")}
    const changeHandler = (value) => { 
        setSearchString(value)}

return(...
     <TextInputCode
          value={searchString}
          onChange={(text) => {
            changeHandler(text);}}
          iconType={
            Platform.OS === "android"
              ? isSearchbarFocused
                ? "chevron-left"
                : "search"
              : "search"
          }
          iconPress={() => {
            Platform.OS === "android" && isSearchbarFocused
              ? (submitHandler(), setSearchbarFocused(false), Keyboard.dismiss())
              : "keine suche";
          }}
          showCancel
          placeholderTextColor={colors.text}
          onFocus={() => {
            setSearchbarFocused(true);
          }}
        />
...)
```

This is the code of my TextInputCode element, but I dont think that this is the problem:

```
const TextInputCode = ({
  iconType,
  placeholder,
  onChange,
  onFocus,
  textContentType,
  autoCapitalize,
  autoCompleteType,
  iconPress,
  onClear
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.inputView}>
      <Icon name={iconType} onPress={iconPress} size={20}    
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          paddingHorizontal: 12,
        }}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        textContentType={textContentType}
        autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
        autoCompleteType={autoCompleteType}
        autoCorrect={false}
        onChangeText={(e) => onChange(e)}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onClear = {onClear}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

I dont understand why this isnt working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `submitHandler()` ?

Comment: @dbuchet sorry, I tested it with brackets but forgot them here

Comment: You're not using `value` in TextInput so it's using the internally managed state instead of your controlled value.